# Node corepack is ignoring packageManager and won't let me set yarn version

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, corepack

I've cloned a project which uses Yarn 1.x and am trying to run it, but I can't find a way to get the right version of Yarn. I think I must be missing something.

Commented Terminal session:

```bash
# using node16.18.0
$ nvm use v16
Now using node v16.18.0 (npm v8.19.2)

# start with no yarn installed
$ yarn --version
zsh: command not found: yarn

# package.json has packageManager set for Yarn v1.22.19
$ cat package.json | grep packageManager
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"

# enable corepack, and it ignores the packageManager version
$ corepack enable
$ yarn --version
3.2.4

# manually ask corepack to use v1.22.19, but it again ignores this
$ corepack prepare yarn@1.22.19 --activate
Preparing yarn@1.22.19 for immediate activation...
$ yarn --version
3.2.4

# manually ask corepack to run yarn 1.22.19, but it again ignores it
$ corepack yarn@1.22.19 --version
3.2.4
```

So using Corepack I don't seem to be able to convince it to use version of Yarn.

In addition installing using `npm install -g` also doesn't seem to work correctly.

```bash
# disable corepack so there's no yarn installed
$ corepack disable
$ yarn --version
zsh: command not found: yarn

# install yarn v1.22.19
$ npm install -g yarn@1.22.19

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 326ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

# somehow it's installed 3.2.4 again
$ yarn --version
3.2.4
```

Comment: What does `which yarn` return?

Comment: @mrienstra for me it returns global yarn (.nvm/versions/node/...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't address the `corepack` issue but I have been able to get `npm install -g yarn@1.22.19` to work. I found a file `~/.yarnrc.yml` which had a version 3.2.4 in it. I'm not sure if the `npm` yarn version was actually incorrect, or if it just used `~/.yarnrc.yml` as its source of truth incorrectly. But regardless when I deleted this file and reinstalled `yarn` globally at the desired version it worked correctly.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue recently. But managed to fix it. (I don't know if it's the correct way of doing it but at least it worked for me)

`which yarn` would return `~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/yarn` and `yarn --version` return `3.2.4`, and this even after doing the exact same thing as you. (trying to install and use yarn `1.22.19`)

Then I figured I would check my home folder `~` and found there a `.yarn` folder and `.yarnrc.yml` file even though i supposedly uninstalled every global installation of yarn.

Removing this `~/.yarn` folder and `~/.yarnrc.yml` file fixed my issue and i was able to use yarn `1.22.19` as expected. `corepack` also stopped ignoring my commands

Hopefully that works for you as well.

Comment: Wow spent like half an hour on this banging my head against a wall. Running `corepack yarn@4.0.1 -v` over and over again and continually seeing `3.6.1`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this as well. Thanks for the helpful pointers on the homepath. On my macos in a new terminal, I watched what was accessing the `~/.yarnrc.yml`

```js
sudo fs_usage | grep /Users/exampleuser/.yarn
```

In a second terminal, I ran

```js
cd ~/exampleproject
yarn set version canary
yarn version
```

This showed me that global telemetry on `yarn@3.2.2` was recreating the `.yml` in my homepath. I disabled it globally

```js
yarn config set --home enableTelemetry 0
```

However, this was not enough to fix, as the watcher showed that `node` was still accessing that file even after everything was deleted, so I had to shutdown all terminals, VSCode, etc.

After taking the above steps, and restarting a new terminal, I was able to get the `yarn version` to respect the project settings.

```js
cd ~/exampleproject
yarn set version canary
yarn --version // correct canary version
yarn install // profit
```

Further, re-enabling telemetry did not have the same effect.

```js
cd ~/exampleproject
yarn config set --home enableTelemetry 1
yarn --version // still respects project version
```

I could only repro the problem via `corepack`

```js
corepack enable
corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate
cd ~/example-project
yarn --version //-> showed corepack version instead of project version
```

which makes me think there's something lurking in there. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

remove .yarn folder and .yarnrc.yml file. it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this was similar to what happened to us but with pnpm there was a .pnpm-global at the home directory and removing it allowed corepack to work as expected.